# Android and ios push notification with aws amplify and fcm

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, aws-amplify

How push notification work with AWS SNS and amplify?
What i guess is AWS SNS will send notification to FCM and SNS is triggering from backend then FCM  will distribute to android devices and for IOS FCM will forward that push notification to APN and APN to IOS devices
Is it correct? 
What is the part of amplify in push notification?
Our login working with amplify.


Is it using in backend or is it need in android and IOS app for reserving  push notification from AWS?
**Note:** *I am using flutter to develop IOS and android app*

How to tigger SNS?

[image: AMAZON-SNS FLUTTER]